# How Many Epochs Should a Neural Net Need to Learn to Square? (Testing Results Included)

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation

Okay, let me preface this by saying that I am well aware that this depends on MANY factors, I'm looking for some general guidelines from people with experience.

My goal is ***not*** to make a Neural Net that can compute squares of numbers for me, but I thought it would be a good experiment to see if I implemented the Backpropagation algorithm correctly. Does this seem like a good idea? Anyways, I am worried that I have not implemented the learning algorithm (fully) correctly.

My Testing (Results):

- **Training Data**: *500* randomly generated numbers between .001 and .999 using Java's Random
- **Network Topology**: **3 Layers** with 1 input neuron, 5 hidden neurons, 1 output neuron
- Weights: All generated to random values between -1 and 1 (java.util.Random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;)
- Uses a bias node: (numOfInputs + 1) so that the input[input.length -1] = 1
- **Activation Function**: Sigmoid
- **Learning Rate**: Shown in results code below
- Have not implemented any sort of momentum, etc
- **Results:**

> ```
> Epochs: 10,000
>
> Learning Rate .25
> 0.5 = [0.24203878039631344]
> 0.9 = [0.7942587190918747]
> 0.1 = [-0.005433286011774396]
>
>
> Changed learning rate to 0.3
>
> 0.5 = [0.2891542106869196]
> 0.9 = [0.8159817287374298]
> 0.1 = [-0.03614377685205278]
>
>
> Changed epoch to 1,000 with .25 learning rate
>
> 0.5 = [0.36399147315079117]
> 0.9 = [0.7585916275848852]
> 0.1 = [-0.02814488264341608]
>
>
> Kept epoch at 1,000 with .30 learning rate
>
> 0.5 = [0.3872669778857468]
> 0.9 = [0.8160049820236891]
> 0.1 = [-0.03328304871978338]
>
>
>
>
>  Epochs: 100,000:
>
>
> .25 learning rate
>
> 0.5 = [0.24533230649123738]
> 0.9 = [0.8146287680498014]
> 0.1 = [0.006935561897963849]
>
>
> .30 learning rate
>
> 0.5 = [0.24660900415003595]
> 0.9 = [0.8097729997778165]
> 0.1 = [0.013269893700964097]
> ```

Are there any other 'simple' 'things' that I should try to train the network with to check its learning abilities?

Comment: Have you experimented with changing the training size? How about the initialization range for weights?

Comment: I have not messed with either. I heard that a weight range of -1 to 1 for Sigmoid function is normal? MLP are supposed to be good at learning from sparse data, correct? Either way, I'm sure that changing these could have a positive or negative effect... Optimizing isn't really my goal. My goal is to see if these results are indicative of good performance or if it may be the case that I didn't implement the algorithm correctly.

Comment: Does you'r random function pick numbers once or in every test? Because there is a chance that in those 500 numbers, 400 will be from 0.0 to 0.2 (for example).

Comment: The function I have to generate training data fills trainingData[] all at once by: trainingInput[x] = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble(); Range min being set to .001 and max set to .999. Then, the data is randomly fed through the network by selecting a randomly generated number between 0 and the trainingData.length. So, there is a high chance that on different training runs some generated data is never used and the data that is used might be in a 0.0 to 0.2 range.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest things you can do is calculating a XOR function. For testing "normal" multilayer perceptrons this is what I normally do. With a learning rate of 0.2 the XOR problem is solved perfectly (99% averaged accuracy) in less than 100 epochs with 2 - 5 - 1 neuron.

With a network (MLP) I have coded (tanh, no bias neuron but bias values for each neuron, weights initialized between 0.1 and 0.5, biases initialized with 0.5 each, 1.000 training data sets from 0.001 to 2.0 and activation normalization (input/activation of all but input layer neurons are divided by the amount of neurons in the parent layer), 1-5-1 neurons) I tried your problem and got a 95% averaged accuracy in less than 2.000 epochs every time with a learning rate of 0.1.

This can have several reasons. For my network 0.001 to 1.0 needed about twice the epochs to learn. Also the mentioned activation normalization (in most cases) reduces the needed epochs to learn a specific problem drastically.

In addition to that I had mostly positive experiences with bias values per neuron instead of one bias neuron per layer.

Furthermore if your learning rate is too high (and you do lots of epochs) you may risk running into overfitting.

Comment: Thanks for the great comment... So, pretty much, something's (back prop) not working correctly on my net

Comment: Probably, yeah...you could supply specific code snippets in a new question, though. Perhaps I am not that much of a help as I am doing neural network stuff for less than a year...but who knows ;) ...and I am sure there are plenty of experts on stackoverflow who could really help to debug.

Comment: @ascenator do you think you could [take a peek at this code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92916/backpropagating-with-neural-network)?

Comment: To be honest, your code looks quite confusing to me. The quality of code is very important if you try to implement solutions for complex problems, otherwise you end up having several bugs hidden in some lines of code and debugging becomes a catastrophe.

Comment: I would suggest you refactor as much as possible first, before starting to debug the code. For example: In my big classes, like neural networks (MLPs, Elman networks, ...) and other complex solutions I follow the rule-of-thumb to have at least twice the amount of comment lines than normal code. Trust me, this eliminates bugs magnitudes faster.

Comment: Concerning the quality of code I would consider it back practice to have no blank lines (for readability) and multiple for-loops, equations and statements in one method. One relatively famous professor at my university (was/is a part-time software consultant for oracle (java related stuff) at several conferences and stuff): If a method contains more than 20 to 30 lines of code or has more than control sequence (e.g. a loop) are not semantically identical, split those things up in smaller methods immediately.

Comment: To give a brief example: my teaching/training methods consist **only** of one for-loop for the desired amount of learning epochs and method calls. No equation, no statement, nothing else. Every single thing is outsourced to smaller methods. *feedforward activation*, *calculating errors*, *updating weights*, *updating biases*, ... are one outsourced method each and those methods themselves got even smaller methods if they start break one of the rules above. Therefore it is really easy to debug and every method can get tests which further enhances debugging.

Comment: A famous software developer (can not remember his name at the moment) once said: quality of code is one of the most important things while developing any kind of software. If you write a method/function, you should try to keep it as simple as possible, so that any other programmer should able to unterstand what is happening in seconds. This is considered good practice, because it boosts debugging, prevents bugs of being implement while developing and enables others and yourself to design new features easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of necroposting, but I thought it would be nice to know for people new to neural networks.

For benchmarking neural networks and machine learning models in general, one common choice is the MONK dataset and its related paper by Thrun, Fahlman et al, which you can download at

http://robots.stanford.edu/papers/thrun.MONK.html

It consists of a set of three easy classification problems, each one is solved with a different machine learning model.

If you look at the neural network chapters, you can see how the input was encoded, which hyperparameters were set (such as number of neurons or learning rate), and what the results were, so you can easily benchmark your own implementation from there.

I think it's a bit more robust than the XOR problem (I talk from experience, since when I was first implementing a neural network, my faulty implementation happened to solve the XOR problem but not the MONK problems).