# Why doesn't this simple neural network converge for XOR?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, xor, backpropagation, convergence

The code for the network below works okay, but it's too slow. [This site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688527/how-many-epochs-should-a-neural-net-need-to-learn-to-square-testing-results-in) implies that the network should get 99% accuracy after 100 epochs with a learning rate of 0.2, while my network never gets past 97% even after 1900 epochs.

```
Epoch 0, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [-0.83054376], Targets [0]
Epoch 100, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.72563824], Targets [1]
Epoch 200, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.87570863], Targets [1]
Epoch 300, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.90996706], Targets [1]
Epoch 400, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [ 0.00204791], Targets [0]
Epoch 500, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.93396672], Targets [1]
Epoch 600, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [ 0.00006375], Targets [0]
Epoch 700, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.94778227], Targets [1]
Epoch 800, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [-0.00149935], Targets [0]
Epoch 900, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [-0.00122716], Targets [0]
Epoch 1000, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [ 0.00457281], Targets [0]
Epoch 1100, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.95921556], Targets [1]
Epoch 1200, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.96001748], Targets [1]
Epoch 1300, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.96071742], Targets [1]
Epoch 1400, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [ 0.00110912], Targets [0]
Epoch 1500, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [-0.00012382], Targets [0]
Epoch 1600, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.9640324], Targets [1]
Epoch 1700, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.96431516], Targets [1]
Epoch 1800, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.97004973], Targets [1]
Epoch 1900, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.96616225], Targets [1]
```

The dataset I'm using is:

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 1
```

The training set is read using a function in a helper file, but that isn't relevant to the network.

```
import numpy as np
import helper

FILE_NAME = 'data.txt'
EPOCHS = 2000
TESTING_FREQ = 5
LEARNING_RATE = 0.2

INPUT_SIZE = 2
HIDDEN_LAYERS = [5]
OUTPUT_SIZE = 1


class Classifier:
    def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
        np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

        self.activ = helper.tanh
        self.dactiv = helper.dtanh

        network = list()
        for i in range(1, len(layer_sizes)):
            layer = dict()
            layer['weights'] = np.random.randn(layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i-1])
            layer['biases'] = np.random.randn(layer_sizes[i])
            network.append(layer)

        self.network = network

    def forward_propagate(self, x):
        for i in range(0, len(self.network)):
            self.network[i]['outputs'] = self.network[i]['weights'].dot(x) + self.network[i]['biases']
            if i != len(self.network)-1:
                self.network[i]['outputs'] = x = self.activ(self.network[i]['outputs'])
            else:
                self.network[i]['outputs'] = self.activ(self.network[i]['outputs'])
        return self.network[-1]['outputs']

    def backpropagate_error(self, x, targets):
        self.forward_propagate(x)
        self.network[-1]['deltas'] = (self.network[-1]['outputs'] - targets) * self.dactiv(self.network[-1]['outputs'])
        for i in reversed(range(len(self.network)-1)):
            self.network[i]['deltas'] = self.network[i+1]['deltas'].dot(self.network[i+1]['weights'] * self.dactiv(self.network[i]['outputs']))

    def adjust_weights(self, inputs, learning_rate):
        self.network[0]['weights'] -= learning_rate * np.atleast_2d(self.network[0]['deltas']).T.dot(np.atleast_2d(inputs))
        self.network[0]['biases'] -= learning_rate * self.network[0]['deltas']
        for i in range(1, len(self.network)):
            self.network[i]['weights'] -= learning_rate * np.atleast_2d(self.network[i]['deltas']).T.dot(np.atleast_2d(self.network[i-1]['outputs']))
            self.network[i]['biases'] -= learning_rate * self.network[i]['deltas']

    def train(self, inputs, targets, epochs, testfreq, lrate):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            i = np.random.randint(0, len(inputs))
            if epoch % testfreq == 0:
                predictions = self.forward_propagate(inputs[i])
                print('Epoch %s, Inputs %s, Outputs %s, Targets %s' % (epoch, inputs[i], predictions, targets[i]))
            self.backpropagate_error(inputs[i], targets[i])
            self.adjust_weights(inputs[i], lrate)


inputs, outputs = helper.readInput(FILE_NAME, INPUT_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE)
print('Input data: {0}'.format(inputs))
print('Output targets: {0}\n'.format(outputs))
np.random.seed(1)

nn = Classifier([INPUT_SIZE] + HIDDEN_LAYERS + [OUTPUT_SIZE])

nn.train(inputs, outputs, EPOCHS, TESTING_FREQ, LEARNING_RATE)
```

Comment: Did you try other learning rates? 0.2 might be too low, and it gets kind of unstable.

Comment: @eventHandler I've updated the post. It's not converging fast enough or accurately enough based on a benchmark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688527/how-many-epochs-should-a-neural-net-need-to-learn-to-square-testing-results-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main bug is that you are doing the forward pass only 20% of the time, i.e. when `epoch % testfreq == 0`:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
  i = np.random.randint(0, len(inputs))
  if epoch % testfreq == 0:
    predictions = self.forward_propagate(inputs[i])
    print('Epoch %s, Inputs %s, Outputs %s, Targets %s' % (epoch, inputs[i], predictions, targets[i]))
  self.backpropagate_error(inputs[i], targets[i])
  self.adjust_weights(inputs[i], lrate)
```

When I take `predictions = self.forward_propagate(inputs[i])` out of `if`, I get much better results faster:

```
Epoch 100, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.80317447], Targets 1
Epoch 105, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [ 0.96340466], Targets 1
Epoch 110, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [ 0.96057278], Targets 1
Epoch 115, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.87960599], Targets 1
Epoch 120, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [ 0.97725825], Targets 1
Epoch 125, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.89433666], Targets 1
Epoch 130, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [ 0.03539024], Targets 0
Epoch 135, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.92888141], Targets 1
```

Also, note that the term *epoch* usually means a single run of *all* of your training data, in your case 4. So, in fact, you are doing 4 times less epochs.

**Update**

I didn't pay attention to the details, as a result, missed few subtle yet important notes:

- the training data in the question represents *OR*, not *XOR*, so my results above are for learning *OR* operation;
- backward pass executes forward pass as well (so it's not a bug, rather a surprising implementation detail).

Knowing this, I've updated the data and checked the script once again. Running the training for 10000 iterations gave ~0.001 average error, so the model *is* learning, simply *not so fast* as it could.

A simple neural network (without embedded normalization mechanism) is pretty sensitive to particular hyperparameters, such as initialization and the learning rate. I tried various values manually and here's what I've got:

```
# slightly bigger learning rate
LEARNING_RATE = 0.3
...
# slightly bigger init variation of weights
layer['weights'] = np.random.randn(layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i-1]) * 2.0
```

This gives the following performance:

```
...
Epoch 960, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [ 0.01392014], Targets 0
Epoch 970, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [ 0.04342895], Targets 0
Epoch 980, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.96471654], Targets 1
Epoch 990, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [ 0.00084511], Targets 0
Epoch 1000, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [ 0.01585915], Targets 0
Epoch 1010, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [-0.004097], Targets 0
Epoch 1020, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [ 0.01898956], Targets 0
Epoch 1030, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [ 0.01254217], Targets 0
Epoch 1040, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [ 0.01429213], Targets 0
Epoch 1050, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.98293925], Targets 1
...
Epoch 1920, Inputs [1 1], Outputs [-0.00043072], Targets 0
Epoch 1930, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.98544288], Targets 1
Epoch 1940, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.97682002], Targets 1
Epoch 1950, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.97684186], Targets 1
Epoch 1960, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [-0.00141565], Targets 0
Epoch 1970, Inputs [0 0], Outputs [-0.00097559], Targets 0
Epoch 1980, Inputs [0 1], Outputs [ 0.98548381], Targets 1
Epoch 1990, Inputs [1 0], Outputs [ 0.97721286], Targets 1
```

The *average accuracy* is close to 98.5% after 1000 iterations and 99.1% after 2000 iterations. It's a bit slower than promised, but good enough. I'm sure it can be tuned further, but it's not the goal of this toy exercise. After all, tanh [is not](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126238/what-are-the-advantages-of-relu-over-sigmoid-function-in-deep-neural-networks) the best activation function, and classification problems should better be solved with cross-entropy loss (rather than L2 loss). So I wouldn't worry too much about performance of this particular network and go on to the logistic regression. That will be definitely better in terms of speed of learning.

Comment: I believe backpropagate() runs a forward pass - no?

Comment: You're training OR not XOR (`Inputs [1 1] ... Targets 1`). But admittedly OP describes an OR logic in their dataset. Looking at OP's output (`Inputs [1 1] ... Targets [0]`) they're training XOR as they say in the title, though.